# Ordering JS Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

So I have some Data:

```
const unorderedData = [
  {checklistIndex: 1, id: 1532, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 3", tasksKey: "2Task 3"},
  {checklistIndex: 2, id: 3969, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 1", tasksKey: "0Task 1"},
  {checklistIndex: 3, id: 561, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 2", tasksKey: "1Task 2"},
  {checklistIndex: 4, id: 6270, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 4", tasksKey: "3Task 4"},
  {checklistIndex: 5, id: 2151, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 3", tasksKey: "2Task 3"},
  {checklistIndex: 6, id: 7776, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 5", tasksKey: "4Task 5"},
  {checklistIndex: 7, id: 689, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 5", tasksKey: "4Task 5"}
];
```

And I wanted to order them where all the

 isDone === true tasks should be ordered from 1 to its length and 
 all of the isDone === false tasks to be ordered from isDonelength to isNotDoneLenght.

so the data should be turned from unordered data to this:

```
const correctAnswer = [
  {checklistIndex: 4, id: 3969, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 1", tasksKey: "0Task 1"},
  {checklistIndex: 5, id: 6270, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 4", tasksKey: "3Task 4"},
  {checklistIndex: 6, id: 7776, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 5", tasksKey: "4Task 5"},
  {checklistIndex: 7, id: 689, isDone: false, taskName: "Task 5", tasksKey: "4Task 5"},
  {checklistIndex: 1, id: 1532, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 3", tasksKey: "2Task 3"},
  {checklistIndex: 2, id: 561, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 2", tasksKey: "1Task 2"},
  {checklistIndex: 3, id: 2151, isDone: true, taskName: "Task 3", tasksKey: "2Task 3"}
];
```

for this here is my function:

```
const fixData = (dataToOrder) => {
  let fixedData = []

  let doneSelectedTasks = dataToOrder.filter(itemData => itemData.isDone);
  let notDoneSelectedTasks = dataToOrder.filter(itemData => !itemData.isDone)

  let fixedDoneTasks = doneSelectedTasks.map((itemData, index) => {
    let newItemData = itemData;
    newItemData.checklistIndex = index+1;
    return newItemData;
  })

  let indexForUnfinishedSelectedTasks = fixedDoneTasks.length+1;
  console.log(indexForUnfinishedSelectedTasks)
  let fixedNotDoneTasks = notDoneSelectedTasks.map((itemData) => {
    let newItemData = itemData;
    newItemData.checklistIndex = indexForUnfinishedSelectedTasks;
    indexForUnfinishedSelectedTasks += 1;
    return newItemData;
  })

  fixedData = fixedNotDoneTasks.concat(fixedDoneTasks);
  return fixedData
}
```

Now Using this function I am getting this as the result

```
[
  {checklistIndex: 4, id: 3969, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 1', tasksKey: '0Task 1'},
  {checklistIndex: 5, id: 6270, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 4', tasksKey: '3Task 4'},
  {checklistIndex: 6, id: 7776, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 5', tasksKey: '4Task 5'},
  {checklistIndex: 7, id: 689, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 5', tasksKey: '4Task 5'},
  {checklistIndex: 1, id: 1532, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 3', tasksKey: '2Task 3'},
  {checklistIndex: 2, id: 561, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 2', tasksKey: '1Task 2'},
  {checklistIndex: 3, id: 2151, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 3', tasksKey: '2Task 3'}
]
```

which apperantly is wrong can anyone tell me why. is it just that my eyes are bad or my coding has a bug in it

Comment: The output of your function is equal to the expected output, by your own definition. I'm not sure I understand what the issue is.

Comment: *"isDone === false tasks to be ordered from isDonelength to isNotDoneLenght*". What is `isDonelength`?

Comment: *"which apperantly is wrong"*  Is it rejected by some online coding site or your teacher? The expected output and your output are same.

Comment: The only issue with this code is `let newItemData = itemData` doesn't create copy of the data. It will still mutate the original object. You could use: `let newItemData = { ...itemData }`

Comment: @adiga I ment isDone === trues filtered list lenght And I see I will just try it and answer back. Also this is a react native project but I am working on this part right now it is actualy my own question

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way :

```js
const data = [
  {checklistIndex: 4, id: 3969, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 1', tasksKey: '0Task 1'},
  {checklistIndex: 5, id: 6270, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 4', tasksKey: '3Task 4'},
  {checklistIndex: 6, id: 7776, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 5', tasksKey: '4Task 5'},
  {checklistIndex: 7, id: 689, isDone: false, taskName: 'Task 5', tasksKey: '4Task 5'},
  {checklistIndex: 1, id: 1532, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 3', tasksKey: '2Task 3'},
  {checklistIndex: 2, id: 561, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 2', tasksKey: '1Task 2'},
  {checklistIndex: 3, id: 2151, isDone: true, taskName: 'Task 3', tasksKey: '2Task 3'}
]
const isDone = data.filter(a => a.isDone === true)
const rest = data.filter(a => a.isDone === false)
isDone.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.checklistIndex - b.checklistIndex;
});
rest.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.checklistIndex - b.checklistIndex;
});
console.log(isDone.concat(rest));
```

Comment: Hello @Theadore thanks for the answer but I just a problems. one is that my data true and false will not aldready be set in order It will be diffrent so If I was to use this code I dont believe it will work as I need the checklist index value of all the items to be put from true to false in oneBases index but thanks for trying